# Using xcodebuild to create .app file for simulator

Tags: swift, xcodebuild

I am trying to use `xcodebuild -workspace '/path/to/Awesome.xcworkspace' -scheme 'Awesome-Production' -arch i386  -sdk iphonesimulator8.2` to build a .app file to point Appium to. I am running into the error `error: iOS 11 does not support 32-bit programs`. This is the only iphonesimulator SDK available when running `xcodebuild -showsdks`: `iphonesimulator12.4`. I can't figure out how to get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

`derivedDataPath` did it for me without the -arch flag. For example: `- xcodebuild -workspace project.xcworkspace/ -scheme project  -sdk $sdk -derivedDataPath "./build"` will dump things in the `build` folder